# Project containing concrete classes is not copied to TestResult directory when using Unity as IoC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, integration-testing, unity-container

I have a solution with several projects in it divided according to DDD principles. One of the integration tests wants to test one of the service method. The method has dependency on ICustomerRepository. 
CustomerRepository is defined in CustomerDomain.Infrastructure assembly and the concrete ICustomerRepository is defined in CustomerDomain.Model assembly.

The dependency is managed by unity configuration file. The mapping is correct and it points out correct assemblies/namespaces and classes. The unity configuration file is copied correctly to the testresult folder. But, when the test runs it fails with the exception: "The type initializer for 'UnityContainerManager' threw an exception." containing inner exception :
"{"The type name or alias CustomerRepository could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name."}"

After some investigation I discovered that CustomerDomain.Model.dll is never copied to testResult dir even if the property Copy Local is set to True.

If I create an instance of CustomerRepository in TestInitialize method everything works - the assembly is copied and the test passes. But this workaround does seem right to me - is there any better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio copies only those referenced assemblies of whom at least one type is used.

If you don't like to create the real `CustomerRepository`, define a dummy type `CopyEnforcer` in the referenced assembly and create an instance of that one in the referencing assembly.